# Stata 16 - create scalar variable using if statement

Tags: stata

I am using Stata 16. I have 2 variables: `totexp` (total medical expenditure) and `suppins` (=1 if has supplementary private insurance) and answering this:

"Claim: The mean total medical expenditure is higher for individuals who have a supplementary private insurance as compared to the individuals who do not. True or False."

So my piece of code is:

```
mean totexp if suppins==0
scalar no_ins = r(mean)

mean totexp if suppins==1
egen yes_ins = mean(totexp) if suppins==1

if yes_ins > no_ins {
display "True"
}

else {
display "False"
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean` has an `over` option, why not use it?

```
sysuse auto
mean price, over(foreign)
```

Or if you want to do a formal test:

```
ttest price, by(foreign)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess at why your code "doesn't work" [in what sense?]

```
mean totexp if suppins==0
scalar no_ins = r(mean)
```

This can be fair technique

```
mean totexp if suppins==1
egen yes_ins = mean(totexp) if suppins==1
```

Why approach this case differently?

```
if yes_ins > no_ins {
    display "True"
}

else {
    display "False"
}
```

Note that you can slim this down to one line:

```
display cond(yes_ins > no_ins, "True", "False")
```

But the code is still risky, for a subtle reason. `yes_ins` is a variable, populated with a mean if the observation is for `suppins == 1` and with missing otherwise. When asked to `display` a variable, Stata displays the value in the first observation. (Think of it this way: it can't possibly display an entire variable on one line unless exceptionally there is only one observation in the dataset.) So it is as if you wrote

```
if yes_ins[1] > no_ins
```

and if `yes_ins[1]` is missing, you may well get the wrong answer.

The answer of @Wouter Wakker gives better solutions. This answer is just focused on a likely reason why the code "doesn't work" and some comments on style.